# How to solve Equation for different variable in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, code-review

I want to solve the given equation for $(n=m=3)$ and I want the output variable $q_{1,1}, q_{1,2}, q_{2,1}, q_{2,2}$

[Given Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GT49.png)

[Given Equation-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVel7.png)

The output should be

[required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqRax.png)

Here is my coding

```
n = 3; m = 3;Solve[Expand[Sum[((n - 1) i - n k)/(i + k) (Binomial[n - 1, k] Binomial[n, l])/(Binomial[2 n - 2, i + k] Binomial[2 n, j + l]) (Subscript[q,k + 1, l] - Subscript[q, k, l]), {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, n - 1}, {k, 0, n - 1}, {l, 0, n}] + Sum[((m - 1) j - n l)/(j + l) (Binomial[n - 1, l] Binomial[n, k])/( Binomial[2 n - 2, j + l] Binomial[2 n, i + k]) (Subscript[q, k, l + 1] - Subscript[q, k, l]), {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1,n - 1}, {k, 0, n}, {l, 0, n - 1}]] == 0,{Subscript[q, 1, 1], Subscript[q, 1, 2], Subscript[q, 2, 1], Subscript[q, 2, 2]}]
```

[coding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnpqU.png)

The code works fine for the case when $n=m=2$ as the only output will be the variable $q_{1,1}$, given in the figure [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4NTs.png).

Comment: One simply copy/pastes code in `InputForm`, then uses the formatting tools (or tabs) to make it a "code" section.

Comment: Also you will need to give `n` a specific value.

Comment: $n=3$ is already provided.

Comment: Okay. The problem is that you do not form polynomials separately for `n = 3;
m = 3;{i,j}=1...n-1`. Can be done like so. `polys = Flatten@
  Table[Expand[
    Sum[((n - 1) i - n k)/(i + 
          k) (Binomial[n - 1, k] Binomial[n, l])/(Binomial[2 n - 2, 
           i + k] Binomial[2 n, j + l]) (q[k + 1, l] - q[k, l]), {k, 
       0, n - 1}, {l, 0, n}] + 
     Sum[((m - 1) j - n l)/(j + 
          l) (Binomial[n - 1, l] Binomial[n, k])/(Binomial[2 n - 2, 
           j + l] Binomial[2 n, i + k]) (q[k, l + 1] - q[k, l]), {k, 
       0, n}, {l, 0, n - 1}]], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, n - 1}]`

Comment: Muhammad, your problem is that you sum over `i`, `j`,`k`, `l`, but in your original equation there are only sums over `k` and `l`

Comment: Now we can get a solution quite easily. `In[399]:= Solve[polys == 0, {q[1, 1], q[1, 2], q[2, 1], q[2, 2]}]`

Comment: Alright. I got the correct output. Thank you.